# How to test property android:autoLink in TestView

Tags: android, robolectric

Need to test if the property is set, how can I do this with Roboletric?

```
private MyActivity activity;

@Before
public void setup() {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivity.class).get();
}

@Test
public void shouldNotBeNull() {
    assertNotNull(activity);

    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.myView);
    assertNotNull(textView);
}


@Test
public void sent_message_list_item_should_autolink() {
    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.myView);


    ShadowTextView shadowView = (ShadowTextView)Robolectric.shadowOf(textView);
    assertTrue(shadowView. //how to get property autolink here?? )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
@Test
public void sent_message_list_item_should_autolink() {
    TextView textView = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.myView);

    assertEquals(Linkify.ALL, textView.getAutolinkMask());
}
```

Also consider of using some assertions library. My preference is [Android AssertJ](http://square.github.io/assertj-android/)